# how to change the extention of my domain name from cars.net to cars.com?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

- I have this domain name (cars.net), and i want to change it to (cars.com) just after the index.php display its content.
- I don't want that the page changes its data after my domain name will change its extention, i want only change the extention of my domain name after the loading of the index.php without any refresh or redirect or change in its data.
- is there any way to do that with jquery or javascript code ? I used this code but it redirects the page and its content and i don't want that, so any help to do that?

  ```
  <script> 
   windows.location.replace("https://cars.com");
  </script>
  ```

Comment: I just want to say that this kind of idea - essentially hijacking existing (and popular) domain names in order to serve your content under those names without owning them, or being associated with them - is exceedingly unethical.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while what they want to do is technically impossible, the intent is highly questionable ethically/legally speaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) can manipulate the path component of the page's URL.

Nothing can change the origin without navigating to the new origin.

It would be a huge boon to people making phishing attacks if they could lie about the domain the visitor was looking at.